# Tab and Stack Navigator on same screen

Tags: react-native

When I navigate to a Tab via push both the Tab Navigator and Stack Navigator are displayed; however, when I navigate to a Stack Navigator via Tab Navigator only the Stack Navigator is displayed. How do I display both the Tab Navigator and Stack Navigator when I push to a Stack Navigator Screen? My app module:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function TabNavigator() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="User" component={UserDetailScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Feed" component={FeedScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}

function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Logout'>
      <Stack.Screen name="Logout" component={LoginScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="User" component={TabNavigator} />
      <Stack.Screen name="UserForm" component={UserFormScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="ItemForm" component={ItemFormScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Swap" component={SwapDetailScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  console.log("test");
  console.log(UserDetailScreen);
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyStack />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The TabBar is only visible when you're inside the TabNav. In your case that's either the UserDetailScreen or the FeedScreen. In order to display both, TabNav and StackNav, you need to change your nesting accordingly.

```
StackNav
 - LoginScreen // no TabBar displayed
 - TabNav
   - UserDetailScreen
   - FeedScreen
 - UserFormScreen // no TabBar displayed
 - ItemFormScreen // no TabBar displayed
 - SwapDetailScreen // no TabBar displayed
```

**Solution A:** put StackNavs into your Tabs (recommended):

```
- TabNav
  -StackNav // e.g. all user related screens
   - LoginScreen
   - UserDetailScreen
   - UserFormScreen
  -StackNav // e.g. all feed related screens
   - FeedScreen
   - ItemFormScreen
   - SwapDetailScreen
```

Hint: if you want to have your login without Tabs you could exclude it from any navigator:

```
- LoginScreen
- TabNav
  -StackNav // e.g. all user related screens
   - UserDetailScreen
   - UserFormScreen
  -StackNav // e.g. all feed related screens
   - FeedScreen
   - ItemFormScreen
   - SwapDetailScreen
```

In your code you can do sth. like this (Pseudocode):

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->    
...    
       render(){
          if (this.state.userIsLoggedIn){
             return <TabNav />;
          } 
          else {
             return <View> My Login Screen </View>
          } 
       }
 ...
```

**Solution B:** use one single Stack and customize your TabNav (might be interesting for some use cases):

```
- TabNav
  - StackNav
    - LoginScreen
    - UserDetailScreen
    - UserFormScreen
    - FeedScreen
    - ItemFormScreen
    - SwapDetailScreen
```

In your code you can do sth. like this (Pseudocode):

```
...
<Tabs.Navigator tabBar = { props => <CustomTabBar {...props} /> }>
   <Tabs.Screen name="TabBar" component={ getScreenStack } />
</Tabs.Navigator>
...
const CustomTabBar  = ({ navigation }) =>  {
   return (
      <View>
        <Button 
         title="User"
         onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('UserScreen') }} 
        />
   )
}

...
function getScreenStack(){
   return (
      <Stack.Navigator>
         <Stack.Screen  name="Login” component=”LoginScreen” />
         ...
     </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}
...
```

If performance is not an issue I would stick to solution A, because solution B has several drawbacks:

- Tab Indicators need to be tracked manually
- Back button behaviour is odd and needs to be adjusted, because Tabs are handled as part of Stack

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why your `FeedScreen` use `<Stack.Screen/>` instead of `Tab.Screen/>`?

```
   <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="User" component={UserDetailScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Feed" component={FeedScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
```

I am confused about this, it may be the problem.